# Access 2007 with SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have Access DB with One StudentTable. I have created multiple queries from that table then Exported to SharePoint Different Sites. Student table is exported to Site Collection.

I added multiple records to Student Table that is uploded in site collection.
Now My problem is - those new records don't get reflected to other list (created queries and exported to SP sites) that are in different sites

Is there any way to work around above problem.

Thank you
Bijaya

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Student Table to a single list and use the DataViewWebpart to roll up different queries to other pages.

If you have everything within the one SiteCollection you are able to use the ContentQuery webpart.